# Crackling on audio file in CD player but not computer?

Tags: software, logic-pro

I wrote a composition and put it into Logic Pro X. I then wanted to burn it to a CD. I bounced it and the resulting file played smoothly on my computer. I imported it into iTunes and burned it to a CD as an Audio CD with titles on. When I played the CD on my CD player connected to an amplifier and speakers, there was a crackling sound. I tried cleaning the CD, but there was still a crackling sound.

My bounce settings:
Format: PCM - Wave
Mode: Realtime
Bounce 2nd Cycle Pass: True
Include Audio Tail: True
Normalize: Off
Resolution: 16 Bit
Sample Rate: 44100
File Type: Interleaved
Dithering: UV22HR

Can you please help me fix this crackling (remove it)? I am using this CD as a birthday present for someone whose birthday is tomorrow.

Comment: What happens when you play the file in iTunes? What about playing the CD on a different CD player - DVD, Blu-Ray players, and game consoles will usually also play audio CDs.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you got a bad burn.  What burn speed did you use?  The old advice of 'as slow as possible for an audio CD' is outdated, but I wouldn't use the advertised maximum (52X?) either.  I find the sweet spot is around 16X or 24X.

There's also the issue that some players just don't like 'burned' CDs.   And even an expensive hi-fi unit may be getting a bit elderly by now, and they do wear out.   It can be hard to persuade a user that the top-price DVD player he bought some years ago is now inferior to a £30 unit from the supermarket.

Anyway, you won't un-crackle the present disk.  Bin it and try another burn at a moderate speed.

Comment: Well, I just tried playing the CD in iTunes and it sounds fine. Could it still be the burn speed?

Comment: What CD drive was the disk in when it crackled?  The one in your computer or another one?
Put the wav (or even MP3) files on a memory stick instead.  CD is a dying format anyway.

Comment: It was in a PrimaLuna ProLogue.

Comment: Blimey!  Classic example of audiophile overkill for a simple digital job.   Or is this a joke?
http://www.primaluna-usa.com/prologue-classic-cd-player/

How old is it?  It doubtless has a standard CD mechanism because, basically that's all there is.

Comment: That’s what it is, but it isn’t mine. It’s my dad’s.

Comment: And also, I meant the amp is a ProLogue. The CD player is a PrimaLuna Classic CD player as you said.

Comment: Like I said, how old?

Comment: 10 years, but with fixes.

Comment: If the fixes didn't include replacing the CD mechanism,  it could be getting pretty tired by now!

Comment: They did involve replacing the CD mechanism.

Comment: I also tried a burn speed of 4x, and the disc played much better, but this time there was a different problem. There was no crackling, but every few seconds it would jitter.

Comment: Did you try the 16x or 24x that I suggested?  And what brand of CD media was it?  But it does seem this player is very fussy!   There are other ways of delivering music  than CD. I suggest you use one.

Comment: 1) I will try 16x. 2) A Staples CD-RW. 3) My parents are... a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: Ah.   Use a CDR, not a CDRW.   That's very likely the main problem.

Comment: the first one was a cdr.

Comment: The cdrw worked better.

Answer (score 0):

Audio CD players tend to have quite less thorough optics as a computer drive (the latter usually has to get along with DVDs if not BluRay and R/W media which have much worse reflective properties than write-once or pressed CDs).

They are also running at quite slower speed so don't have as many reread attempts before running out of time for smooth play.

Early CD players did not get along with burnt CDs at all.  Your best bet are specific audio CDs (usually with some Azo coloring layer) having high contrast and producing reasonably well-formed pits.  You don't know just how old any CD player your friend may be having can be, and those are the safest media for distribution.